Apply discount on products customizable options only
I’ve been working on a feature that requires applying discounts based on specific product custom attributes (Customizable Options).
For example, I have 5 custom attributes (size, color, style, material, brand) for a product. I want to apply a 40% discount on the price for the selected Color and a 10% discount for the selected Style, without affecting the main product price. And it should be done in the product details page.
Is that possible? Do you have any suggestions or ideas? Thank you.

Actually you need to write your own custom logic for PDP page using jQuery to show the price based on selected options and when product added in cart then you can modify the product price accordingly using the checkout_cart_product_add_after event

Thank you very much for the guidance.
